# How to wait until parameters are defined in order to make call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rest, asynchronous

I am building a React cryptocurrency project for my portfolio and im just trying to figure out how I can solve this issue where the api call is taking null parameters. As you might see, I am polling for data upon render of the component, however, I am seeing the error in the console that the parameters are null. I would like to have the api request wait until the parameters are actually not null to make the api request. Here is my code and the url that returns a null value for the currencies to be used:

> ```
> /api/v1/private/quote?pair=null/null&side=BUY&amount=
> ```

```
  const baseAsset = transactionType === TRANSACTION_TYPES.BUY ? selectedCurrencyState.selectedToCurrency : selectedCurrencyState.selectedFromCurrency;
  const quoteAsset = transactionType === TRANSACTION_TYPES.SELL ? selectedCurrencyState.selectedToCurrency : selectedCurrencyState.selectedFromCurrency;



const handleGetSwapPrice = () => {
    const amountValue = TRANSACTION_TYPES.BUY ? amountState.fromCurrencyAmount : amountState.toCurrencyAmount;
    getSwapPrice(`${baseAsset}/${quoteAsset}`, transactionType, amountValue)
      .then((res) => {
        const formattedPrice = formatCurrency('USD', res.price);
        setSwapPrice(formattedPrice);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      getSwapPairs()
        .then((res) => {
          setSwapInfo(res.markets);
          if (transactionType === TRANSACTION_TYPES.BUY) {
            setSelectedCurrencyState({ ...selectedCurrencyState, selectedFromCurrency: localStorage.getItem('fromCurrency') || 'USD', selectedToCurrency: 'BTC' || localStorage.getItem('toCurrency') });
          }
          setTransactionType(localStorage.getItem('transactionType', transactionType) || TRANSACTION_TYPES.BUY);
        });

      const timer = setInterval(handleGetSwapPrice, 6000);
      return () => clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, []);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this code. `getSwapPairs()` fetches .. something? But then `getSwapPrice()` doesn't depend on it at all. Can you complete the code fragment? What is `selectedCurrencyState/setSelectedCurrencyState?`. Should it be possible to call `handleGetSwapPrice` from like a button or something? Why are you calling it in the `useEffect?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useMemo` or `useCallback` (preferred `useCallback`) for that `handleGetSwapPrice`  function.

Like this:

```js
const handleGetSwapPrice = useCallback(() => {
  const amountValue = TRANSACTION_TYPES.BUY ? amountState.fromCurrencyAmount : amountState.toCurrencyAmount;
  getSwapPrice(`${baseAsset}/${quoteAsset}`, transactionType, amountValue)
    .then((res) => {
      const formattedPrice = formatCurrency('USD', res.price);
      setSwapPrice(formattedPrice);
    });
}, [baseAsset, quoteAsset, transactionType, amountState]);
```

And since you call that function from useEffect, you need to make those variables dependencies for it:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (isLoggedIn && baseAsset && quoteAsset) {
    getSwapPairs()
      .then((res) => {
        setSwapInfo(res.markets);
        if (transactionType === TRANSACTION_TYPES.BUY) {
          setSelectedCurrencyState({ ...selectedCurrencyState, selectedFromCurrency: localStorage.getItem('fromCurrency') || 'USD', selectedToCurrency: 'BTC' || localStorage.getItem('toCurrency') });
        }
        setTransactionType(localStorage.getItem('transactionType', transactionType) || TRANSACTION_TYPES.BUY);
      });

    const timer = setInterval(handleGetSwapPrice, 6000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, [baseAsset, quoteAsset]);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. The `useEffect` is going to call the function bound to the initial values.

Comment: Still no good. `handleGetSwapPrice` should be a dependency at least.